# Binary SMS on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, binary, sms

I'm looking for information about how binary SMS are implemented on iPhone.

Particularly I would like to know what you need to do (if it is possible) in an iOS application to

- listen to a specific SMS port and
- then be notified of a dedicated incoming binary SMS.

Of course, I'm looking for a solution based on official (public) APIs.

Answer (score 3):

There is no offcial API to access SMS database of iphone without jailbreaking of it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, you can only send a SMS via de official API. You can't read the SMS inbox let alone listen for incoming SMSes.

Comment: rckoenes: Could you let me know how to listen for incoming SMSes in iPhone

Comment: You can't listen for incoming SMSes on the iPone on a non jailbroken iPhone.