# Showing sms dialog in ios for certain number

Tags: objective-c, ios

I know iOS is very strict about accessing sms and user data. But I wish to implement simple feature, something like log.

In my app user sends sms to another number (robot). And gets it's state back in sms. I know I can't access them in any way. But maybe I can set up a button which would simply show sms from certain number if there are any. Just to open Messages for a certain number that's all.

Is that possible, and can be accepted by Apple?

[image: PopUp window]

Comment: I do not wish to view any messages. I just wish to open messages from a certain number. I do not wish to read, or get them at all. Just like I can popup message window with certain number and certain message in it (and it is up to user to send it or not), can't i popup message dialog for certain number? Not possible?

Comment: If your question is to send an sms, you can do that. Use MFMessageComposeViewController for the same. You can send an sms to any number using that. Only thing is it will ask user's confirmation before sending it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only send an sms. You cant view any messages. Check the [apple documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/SystemMessaging_TopicsForIOS/Articles/SendinganSMSMessage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010416-SW1).
Apart from usage of `MFMessageComposeViewController`, only option you have is to open the message app as,

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"sms:"]];
```

Or just to pop up the sms app with number as,

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"sms:1234567890"]];
```

Here is a [similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442777/binary-sms-on-iphone)

**Update:**

If you want to do this inside your app, you can use `MFMessageComposeViewController`. Check [this apple documentation for more details on this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: You still misunderstood my question or I your answer. I'v updated a question with picture of what I would like to do. I'd like to open a messages from lets say ANDY and that's all, its up to user what he does with it. Can't do that ?

Comment: @Datenshi, No. That is not possible. You can just open the sms app. You cant do anything more than that. I got confused with this comment of yours as "and it is up to user to send it or not". That is why I added the update. My first part clarifies your question that you can only send sms and just open the sms app. Nothing more than that is possible in normal ways.

Comment: Ok, Thanks that's that I wanted to know !